# How to import uPLibrary to Unity to work with HoloLens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm trying to create an MQTT client to establish a communication between HoloLens and an MQTT broker. I created a script inside the Assets folder and tried to write an MQTT client using the following libraries.

```
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt;
using uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages;
```

But how do I import these libraries to the project? I'm new to C# so I'm not aware of any build tools that can be used.

Appreciate any advice on this regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish three cases having two different DLLs:

1. Running on HoloLens
2. The native [HoloLens
   emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-hololens-emulator).
3. Unity editor simulation i.e. Holographic Emulation or simulator (s.
   [Introducing Holographic
   Emulation](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/09/29/introducing-holographic-emulation/))

1 and 3 are base on UWP while Unity editor is using .NET framework (4.X nowadays). For accessing uPLibrary namespace from UWP copy the M2Mqtt.WinRT.DLL to somewhere under your Assets directory select it and edit its import settings like this:
[image]

To make things work in Unity simulator too, copy M2Mqtt.Net.DLL and edit the import settings so that *Any Platforms* is clicked and *WSAPlayer* is excluded.

You don't have to make any distinctions in code and can access MqttClient and other classes platform independent like for iOS or Android.